# How to resolve 'could not initialize an instance of the type uikit.uiimage : The native initwith contentsofFile' errors in icons tabbed page

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am very struggle to fix this strange issue. In my application using tabbed page with icons but when try to build getting exception. From last three months it's working fine. last day on wards it's getting build issue. please suggest any idea to fix this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1) Check that build action for icon is set to Bundle Resource

2) Check the file name. If it contains capital letters, remove the file from the project, rename to lowercase and then add again.

Comment: Thank's Taier, I am adding images in 'IMAGE.XCASSETS' in IOS resource folder and another thing is I am using lower case naming's only.